# Invoke a jQuery function on div clicking on different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a jQuery validation function.

```
function validationCheck() {
  if($(this).val()==''){
    $(this).addClass('validation-error');
    return false;
  }
}
```

I need to invoke this function when I click on a button.

```
$('#stepbutton1').click(function(){
  $("#geocomplete").validationCheck(); //Call the function (this wont work)
});
```

How can I invoke this function to check the validation on the id `stepbutton1` ?

Comment: I have two textfields in the step1 and another two in step 2. Currently the step2 is hidden to that also I wish apply the same function for validation. So removing the identifier would be prone to bug nah?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add function to jQuery `prototype`, it will be small [jQuery plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

```js
$.fn.validationCheck = function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  if ($this.val() == ''){
    $this.addClass('validation-error');
    return false;
  }
}

$('#stepbutton1').click(function(){
   $("#geocomplete").validationCheck();
});
```

```css
.validation-error {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="stepbutton1">stepbutton1</button>
<input id="geocomplete" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass an element to the function as an argument:

```
function validationCheck(element) {
    if($(element).val()==''){
        $(this).addClass('validation-error');
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then call it accordingly:

```
$('#stepbutton1').click(function(){
    validationCheck('#geocomplete');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of `this` is not the input when in the context of the `validationCheck()` function. Just pass the target input to the validation function rather than making it the receiver.
http://jsfiddle.net/32z20jcz/1/

```
$('#stepbutton1').click(function () {
    validationCheck($('#geocomplete'));
});

function validationCheck(input) {
    if (input.val() == '') {
        input.addClass('validation-error');
        return false;
    }
}
```